# A moderator delete my answer and I diagree with his decision. How can I contact him?

Tags: support

A moderator deleted one of my answers and explained why he did this. However, I disagree and want to clarify this / ask him about this.

I can just undelete my answer and edit it, but I feel like this would be rude - as if I bypass his decision. Comments on deleted answers are disabled, so I can't comment. Also, I can't find a PM system on his profile where I could contact him. Maybe I miss something.

What should I do to clarify this?

Comment: Discussing issues with content can be done on meta. I would just bring forward arguments on meta and wait how the community and the moderator reacts. If you convince the community, the moderator will likely follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can just undelete my answer

[Nope, you can't.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/295232) - just try it and see what happens.

> How can I contact him?

♦ moderators get notified about new Meta posts on their sites, so they'll see this question and might choose to explain their decision in more detail. Or, as Izzy notes, when another moderator sees it first, that moderator might investigate and ping the responsible moderator in their moderator chatroom.

Another option (if you have compelling arguments that might not have been considered by the moderator, or have edited your post to solve the problems they indicated in their comment) would be to use a custom moderator flag.

Normally, you'd be able to reply on comments, but since only ♦ moderators can leave comments on deleted posts, that's not an option here.